# Pass table row data on click to child component

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a webpage that contains a table. [Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDrbE.png)

Now I want to update table row data on click (table row). I have done the "on click" part. After clicking on table row: [This child page opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TrlU.png)

Now I want to pass table row data on click to the child component form textboxes. How can I do that?

Parent component code:

```
  export class QuotationForm extends React.Component<AllProps>{
      public componentDidMount() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        if (data.length === 0) {
          this.props.fetchRequest()
        }
      }
      public render() {
        const { loading, data, errors } = this.props
        console.log(errors);
        return (
          <Page>
                {loading && (
                  <LoadingOverlay>
                    <LoadingOverlayInner>
                      <LoadingSpinner />
                    </LoadingOverlayInner>
                  </LoadingOverlay>
                )}
                {/* <p>
                  <small>Quotation Data Of Shiping</small>
                </p> */}
                {this.renderData(loading, data)} 
          </Page>
        )
      }
      handleClick(quot:any){
        alert(quot.quotationNumber)
        console.log("passing data",quot)
      }
      private renderData(loading: boolean, data: IQuotation[]) {
        const { classes }: any = this.props;
        console.log("Quotation Data", this.props)
        return (
          <div className={classes.section}>
            <Table className={classes.tableStyle}>
              <TableHead className={classes.thead} >
                <TableRow >
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>QuotationNumber</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Date</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Quoted To</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Quoted By</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Valid Till</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Valid From</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Services</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Status</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Location</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              {loading && data.length === 0}

              {data.map((quot) => (

              <TableBody className={classes.tbody}>
              <TableRow hover  key={quot.quotationNumber} className={classes.tcell}> 
                    <TableCell><a href="/quotationUpdate" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,quot)}>{quot.quotationNumber}</a></TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.date}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.quotedTo}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.quotedBy}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.validTill}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.validFrom}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.services}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.status}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.location}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              </TableBody>))}
            </Table>
          </div>)
      }
    }
```

Child component code (after clicking on table row this page is rendering):

```
class quotationUpdate extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {classes}:any=this.props;
        return (
            <div>    
                <h3 style={{color:"black"}}>Update Data</h3>

                    <Card className={classes.cardStyle}>
                    <form style={{ padding: "5%" }}>
                        <Table className={classes.tableStyle} >
                            <TableRow>
                                <h5><TableCell>Quotation No<TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell>
                                {/* {console.log(quotationNuber)} */}
                                    <TableCell>Valid From <TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Vaild Till<TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell></h5>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                                <h5><TableCell>Organization<TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Useability<TextField select variant="outlined" defaultValue="None" fullWidth helperText="Please Select Value">
                                        <MenuItem value=""><em>None</em></MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value={0}>Single</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value={1}>Multiple</MenuItem>
                                    </TextField>
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Version<TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell></h5>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                                <h5><TableCell>FastTrack<TextField multiline variant="outlined" /></TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Party Role <TextField select disabled defaultValue="Customer" fullWidth variant="outlined" /></TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Cargo Status<TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell></h5>
                            </TableRow>
                        </Table><br /><br />
```

Comment: Please paste your code here.It's difficult to judge this by seeing image

Comment: @NaieemMahmudSupto Please see my code

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the table component gets the data in the props, this means that the loaded data exists in the parent component. So inside the click handle you have to "mark" the selected row, in order to "detect" it when the `quotationUpdate` is rendered...

You can send `onRowSelected` function in the props, in order to "mark" the selected row once it's clicked.

This solution isn't so "nice" and won't hold very well in future changes...

You are encountering the classical state management issue in react. There are many ways to solve this, and most "battle-tested" solution is redux.

Comment: ( click handle you have to "mark" the selected row, in order to "detect" is when the quotationUpdate is rendered...) how to do?????

Comment: You can send `onRowSelected` function in the props, in order to "mark" the selected row once it's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here you are changing route. So a new component is taking action then.In this case you can do one thing.Create a service where you will save data temporarily and after changing route update route will get data from the service.Let's see the example.

```
 class sharedService(){
    static storeData:any;
    constructor(){
    }
}
```

Now import this to both of your component.Your parent component will look like this.

```
import sharedService from 'your file location';

export class QuotationForm extends React.Component<AllProps>{
      public componentDidMount() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        if (data.length === 0) {
          this.props.fetchRequest()
        }
      }
      public render() {
        const { loading, data, errors } = this.props
        console.log(errors);
        return (
          <Page>
                {loading && (
                  <LoadingOverlay>
                    <LoadingOverlayInner>
                      <LoadingSpinner />
                    </LoadingOverlayInner>
                  </LoadingOverlay>
                )}
                {/* <p>
                  <small>Quotation Data Of Shiping</small>
                </p> */}
                {this.renderData(loading, data)} 
          </Page>
        )
      }
      handleClick(quot:any){
        alert(quot.quotationNumber)
        console.log("passing data",quot)
        sharedService.storeData=quot;
      }
      private renderData(loading: boolean, data: IQuotation[]) {
        const { classes }: any = this.props;
        console.log("Quotation Data", this.props)
        return (
          <div className={classes.section}>
            <Table className={classes.tableStyle}>
              <TableHead className={classes.thead} >
                <TableRow >
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>QuotationNumber</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Date</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Quoted To</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Quoted By</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Valid Till</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Valid From</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Services</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Status</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tcell}>Location</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              {loading && data.length === 0}

              {data.map((quot) => (

              <TableBody className={classes.tbody}>
              <TableRow hover  key={quot.quotationNumber} className={classes.tcell}> 
                    <TableCell><a href="/quotationUpdate" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,quot)}>{quot.quotationNumber}</a></TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.date}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.quotedTo}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.quotedBy}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.validTill}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.validFrom}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.services}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.status}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quot.location}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              </TableBody>))}
            </Table>
          </div>)
      }
    }
```

now your update component will look like this.

```
    import sharedService from 'your file location';
    class quotationUpdate extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const {classes}:any=this.props;
const data = sharedService.storeData;
            return (
                <div>    
                    <h3 style={{color:"black"}}>Update Data</h3>

                        <Card className={classes.cardStyle}>
                        <form style={{ padding: "5%" }}>
                            <Table className={classes.tableStyle} >
                                <TableRow>
                                    <h5><TableCell>Quotation No<TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell>
                                    {/* {console.log(quotationNuber)} */}
                                        <TableCell>Valid From <TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>Vaild Till<TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell></h5>
                                </TableRow>
                                <TableRow>
                                    <h5><TableCell>Organization<TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>Useability<TextField select variant="outlined" defaultValue="None" fullWidth helperText="Please Select Value">
                                            <MenuItem value=""><em>None</em></MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={0}>Single</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={1}>Multiple</MenuItem>
                                        </TextField>
                                        </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>Version<TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell></h5>
                                </TableRow>
                                <TableRow>
                                    <h5><TableCell>FastTrack<TextField multiline variant="outlined" /></TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>Party Role <TextField select disabled defaultValue="Customer" fullWidth variant="outlined" /></TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>Cargo Status<TextField variant="outlined" /></TableCell></h5>
                                </TableRow>
                            </Table><br /><br />
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: A global shared stated isn't a good idea... According to your solution the `data` that's being injected in the props can also be in this global shared state... bad idea

Comment: I know that.But he is changing the route and also not using any http call,what else he can do here rather sharing that? @gilamran

Comment: He should pass a the data to display, and a function to "mark" the selected row. In the parent component when this function is called, mark the selected row.

Comment: I think here problem is not about marking the table rather he wants to pass the data to the next route.Please check the question carefully.